# Cannot extract exported eclipse product (exported as archive)

Tags: windows, eclipse-rcp, archive

I export an eclipse RCP application (defined in a .product file) as an archive. But when I try to extract it using windows 7 build in extract tool I just get:

corrupted archive

I can extract the archive using 7zip though. Why can windows7 not open the archive created by eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think I have seen this too.

Then it turned out to be an entry for the directory/folder that caused the trouble - i.e an entry on the form `plugin/`. The last slash was not accepted.